# Run MariaDB on Visual Studio 2010 from the source code

Tags: mariadb

I tried to run MariaDb on the visual studio 2010, the build is successfully but and when I debug the code it shows this message:

These projects are out of date:

GenError - Debug Win32
    GenServerSource - Debug Win32
    GenFixPrivs - Debug Win32
    initial_database - Debug Win32

Please could any one help me?

thanks in advance.

Comment: so? Does that actually prevent you from debugging it? Those projects sound like projects for generating files that are probably by design "always outdated" so that they're recreated each build

Comment: I solved it but it comes this message:

Unable to start the program 'C\mariadb-5.2.14\bld\Debug\ALL_BUILD'

The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: You tried to execute the project "ALL_BUILD". It has no executable to run. You need to change the startup project to some other project that actually has something to execute.